# Cannot open Realm database in React Native using Realm Studio

Tags: react-native, realm

I create, open and write on a realm database using following functions:

To load the database or to create a new one I am using:

```
let realm = new Realm({
  path: 'UserDatabase.realm',
  schema: [
    {
      name: 'user_details',
      properties: {
        user_id: {type: 'int', default: 0},
        user_name: 'string',
        user_contact: 'string',
        user_address: 'string',
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

Write some data:

```
let realmWrite = () => {
  if (realm === null || realm === undefined) {
    console.error('realm is:' + realm);
  } else {
    realm.write(() => {
      var ID = 1;
      realm.create('user_details', {
        user_id: ID,
        user_name: 'username' + ID,
        user_contact: 'contact',
        user_address: `asd${ID}@asd.asd`,
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Apparently writing data doesn't work, so I try to open the database using Realm Studio and I get following errors:

```
CLASSES
Unable to open a realm at path '/Users/shinigami/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DEB97125-E440-4AAA-9326-7E2B8D29F158/data/Containers/Data/Application/F2B137EF-F864-454D-A622-184C95C39EEE/Documents/UserDatabase.realm': Invalid top array (ref: 1080, size: 11)
Exception backtrace:
0 .io.realm.realm-studio.SwVRf2 0x000000010dcfe581 _ZN5realm15InvalidDatabaseC2ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES9_ + 49
1 .io.realm.realm-studio.SwVRf2 0x000000010dcec970 _ZN5realm5Group18validate_top_arrayERKNS_5ArrayERKNS_9SlabAllocE + 1632
2 .io.realm.realm-studio.SwVRf2 0x000000010dcf6a20 _ZN5realm11SharedGroup7do_openERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEEbbNS_18SharedGroupOptionsE + 5136
3 .io.realm.realm-studio.SwVRf2 0x000000010d9f9a8c _ZN5realm11SharedGroup4openERNS_11ReplicationENS_18SharedGroupOptionsE + 236
4 .io.realm.realm-studio.SwVRf2 0x000000010d9f9473 _ZN5realm11SharedGroupC2ERNS_11ReplicationENS_18SharedGroupOptionsE + 1587
5 .io.realm.realm-studio.SwVRf2 0x000000010d964951 _ZN5realm5Realm16open_with_configERKNS0_6ConfigERNSt3__110unique_ptrINS_11ReplicationENS4_14default_deleteIS6_EEEERNS5_INS_11SharedGroupENS7_ISB_EEEERNS5_INS_5GroupENS7_ISF_EEEEPS0_ + 1145
6 .io.realm.realm-studio.SwVRf2 0x000000010d964286 _ZN5realm5RealmC2ENS0_6ConfigENSt3__110shared_ptrINS_5_impl16RealmCoordinatorEEE + 278
7 .io.realm.realm-studio.SwVRf2 0x000000010d984a40 _ZZN5realm5Realm17make_shared_realmENS0_6ConfigENSt3__110shared_ptrINS_5_impl16RealmCoordinatorEEEEN19make_shared_enablerC2ES1_S6_ + 84
8 .io.realm.realm-studio.SwVRf2 0x000000010d96ab44 _ZNSt3__110shared_ptrIZN5realm5Realm17make_shared_realmENS2_6ConfigENS0_INS1_5_impl16RealmCoordinatorEEEE19make_shared_enablerE11make_sharedIJS3_S6_EEES8_DpOT_ + 136
9 .io.realm.realm-studio.SwVRf2 0x000000010d97fa3c _ZN5realm5_impl16RealmCoordinator12do_get_realmENS_5Realm6ConfigERNSt3__110shared_ptrIS2_EERNS4_11unique_lockINS4_5mutexEEEb + 260
10 .io.realm.realm-studio.SwVRf2 0x000000010d97f8aa _ZN5realm5_impl16RealmCoordinator9get_realmENS_5Realm6ConfigE + 352
11 .io.realm.realm-studio.SwVRf2 0x000000010d9665fb _ZN5realm5Realm16get_shared_realmENS0_6ConfigE + 113
12 .io.realm.realm-studio.SwVRf2 0x000000010d8cb2cb _ZN5realm2js10RealmClassINS_4node5TypesEE19create_shared_realmEPN2v87IsolateENS_5Realm6ConfigEbONSt3__13mapINSA_12basic_stringIcNSA_11char_traitsIcEENSA_9allocatorIcEEEENSB_ISH_NS0_9ProtectedINS5_5LocalINS5_5ValueEEEEENSA_4lessISH_EENSF_INSA_4pairIKSH_SM_EEEEEESO_NSF_INSP_ISQ_ST_EEEEEEONSB_ISH_NSI_INSJ_INS5_8FunctionEEEEESO_NSF_INSP_ISQ_S10_EEEEEE + 127
13 .io.realm.realm-studio.SwVRf2 0x000000010d8c96c6 _ZN5realm2js10RealmClassINS_4node5TypesEE11constructorEPN2v87IsolateENS5_5LocalINS5_6ObjectEEERNS0_9ArgumentsIS3_EE + 402
14 .io.realm.realm-studio.SwVRf2 0x000000010d8c8a1b _ZN5realm4node10ObjectWrapINS_2js10RealmClassINS0_5TypesEEEE9constructERKN3Nan20FunctionCallbackInfoIN2v85ValueEEE + 333
15 .io.realm.realm-studio.SwVRf2 0x000000010d8c9412 _ZN3Nan3impL23FunctionCallbackWrapperERKN2v820FunctionCallbackInfoINS1_5ValueEEE + 166
16 Electron Framework 0x0000000102c1e4a8 _ZN2v88internallsERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEERKNS0_18BasicBlockProfilerE + 350504
...
```

What's wrong?

---

> Update

Inspecting manually the realm file I see that the file is written and filled "*as expected*". Please, note **username** and **asd1@asd.asd** that are literal strings from the writing function.

[image]

Comment: Same issue on `RN 0.61.5`/`Realm 4.0.0-beta.0`.

Answer (score 2):

I solved by updating Realm Studio to its [beta version](http://studio-releases.realm.io/v3.9.0-beta.0).

From:

[image]

to:

[image]

This because I was trying to open a v4 Realm JS file by using with the latest version of Studio **which uses Realm JS v3 internally**. So I have had to download and use the beta version of Realm Studio, which uses v4.